# Data Streamer add-in not present in COM add in list

Tags: excel, arduino-uno, excel-addins, comaddin

As previously stated in the title, I don't see Data Streamer in the add-in list of COM add-ins, where can I download it and which file do I choose to add it?
Also, if I'm unable to get data streamer on my version (I'm using the student version of MS Office), what are the alternatives?
I wish to connect my Arduino Uno to Excel.
[This is my current add-ins list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40mdA.png)

Edit 1: I downloaded the Data Streamer from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56976

And added the setup.exe file to com add-ins which downloaded the file unfortunately, it still isn't coming in the list.
Please view the following images to get an idea of the error.

[As you can see, it downloaded successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Aeis.png)

[This is the list after downloading Data Streamer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUmoW.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. First close your Excel 2016 Pro plus
2. go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56976
3. download Data Streamer_4_0_0_0.zip
4. Unzip and click on setup file ..wait for few second
5. Install it
6. run MSExcel
7. Go to Developer tab ( if it is not there than Right click in "Home Tab" select Developer tool in right side panel than press ok)
   [image]
8. Go to "COMM Addin" Unselect all addins
9. than again select all addins
10. It will appear in tab

[image]